# Proxy/SSL inspection on electron stylesheet load?

Tags: electron

I've got an electron `vue.js` app and I was trying to use `vuetify` which has you load a style sheet from google.  In my `index.html` i have the following call:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro"/>
```

I'm getting an error in chrome
[image]

If I change it to:  `http` instead of `https` I get a `403` error

I am able (however) to have the main browser window open this

```
mainWindow.loadURL(
  'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700|Material+Icons', 
  { 'userAgent': 'curl' })
```

So I'm not sure whats going on.

My special case (of course) is i'm behind a corporate firewall with SSL inspection and a self signed certificate.  I'm having trouble figuring exactly how to fix/debug this issue - as I'm sure its related to the firewall/ssl issue.

Testing the behavior (with disk cache disabled)

```
fetch('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700|Material+Icons')
    .then(data => {
         data.text() // could be .text() or .blob() depending on the data you are expecting
         .then(y => console.log(y)); // print your data
     });
```

Also yields the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seemed to fix things:

```
mainWindow.webContents.setUserAgent('curl')
```